# Single form for parent and all children in relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

In my RoR I have a table `games`, `stats`, and `players`. Each game has many `players,` each player has many 'stats,' and each games has many `stats` through `players.` What i want to be able to do is in on my edit games form, i want there to be a a row of fields to add a new stat row, one per each players the game has. Ive been reading a lot about nested_attributes, but found new good resources how to fully do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Here's an updated set of classes based on the new associations you've stated in your comment

```
# models/game.rb
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams
  attr_accessible :name, :teams_attributes
end
```

---

```
# models/team.rb
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  has_many :players
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :players
  attr_accessible :name, :players_attributes
end
```

---

```
# models/player.rb
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :stats
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stats, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }
  attr_accessible :name, :stats_attributes
end
```

---

```
# models/stat.rb
class Stat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

---

```
# controllers/games_controller.rb
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    @game.teams.each do |team|
      team.players.each do |player|
        player.stats.build
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    if @game.update_attributes(params[:game])
      render "show"
    else
      render text: "epic fail"
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
# games/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @game do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :teams do |tf| %>
    <p>Team: <%= tf.object.name %></p>
    <%= tf.fields_for :players do |pf| %>
      <p>Player: <%= pf.object.name %></p>
      <%= pf.fields_for :stats do |sf| %>
        <%= sf.text_field :name %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

Note this doesn't do any sort of ajax "add another stat" or anything fancy. It just sticks one extra blank field at the end for each player. If you needed more, you could build more blank stat objects in the `GamesController#edit` action or implement some fancy pants javascript. Hopefully that will get you close enough to be able to get your real data working.

Comment: First thanks for this, theres a lot of new things i never knew of before. So let me now explain something that i originally explained to you wrong. A `game` has many `teams`, and a `team` has many `players`. So in the `GamesController#edit`, i changed it to `@game.home_team.players.each do |player|
           player.stats.build
          end` and here are two lines in my view that is bringing the error `undefined method 'name'`, `<% f.fields_for :players do |pf| %> <p>Stats for: <%= pf.object.name %></p>` Any idea what might be causing this error? Let me know if my explanation is too confusin

Comment: Looks like your `Player` model doesn't have a `name` attribute. `<%= pf.object.name %>` is just pulling the current player's name that the FormBuilder object is representing as it iterates over the `players` collection. You need to change the `.name` bit to whatever attribute fits your `Player` model (perhaps `full_name`, `first_name`, `fname` etc.) Let me know if you need me to update my answer with the new values if you still have problems.

Comment: No there is indeed a name column.

Comment: Is it saying `undefined method 'name'` for `nil` then? What's the full error?

Comment: It just says undefined method. I appreciate your help and im going to do some work and try to make it work on my own, thanks ill post more questions if i cant succeed

Comment: Well all of that code is from a working sample app I created, so there's something important being left out of your problem description that doesn't match what I've written. If you're abandoning this question, accepting my answer would be much appreciated, since I did twice provide working solutions to what you asked.

Comment: You got it, chances are ill be uploaded an updated question later on. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

without seeing more of your own code, I can't be specific, but basically, you loop over all the players and "build" the stats...  game.players.each {|p| p.build_stat}   and then in the form, loop over all the players again, and display the stats (maybe limiting to the new_record? ones?)     Or perhaps do the build right in the form so it shows a blank entry.

I think I see a potential problem though, with your models... If the stats are a specific representation of a specific game, then your model as you describe it doen't link them - you'd need a game_id and player_id in each stat record.   If that were the case, you would build all the stats in the controller method, and loop over them in the view.

Comment: I saw this. Its similar, but not the same. In that one, they just add new rows in a child's table.I need to add add new rows in a child table (stat) foreach player that the team has

Comment: Do you need to have a form shown for every stat, or is it calculated somehow?

Comment: @Dmg yeah i need a form for every stat. And you are correct, all the stats do have a game_id and player_id, nice catch.